# Junit 5 test class structure

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

Hi I'm beginner with JUnit as well as testing generally. Probably it's overthinking but I wonder about good practices with test code structure. I tried few approaches. I will be grateful for any advice.

First approach: Placing arguments, inputs, outputs at top of class. Then it's easily to check or change testing conditionals for whole class:

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class App {

    private DecimalRepresentation decimal;

    private final int[] positiveArguments = { 10, 50, 2500 };
    private final int[] negativeArguments = { -10, -50, -2500 };

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        decimal = new DecimalRepresentation();
    }

    private Stream<Arguments> createPositiveBinaryArguments() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(positiveArguments[0], "1010"),
                Arguments.of(positiveArguments[1], "110010"),
                Arguments.of(positiveArguments[2], "100111000100"));
    }

    private Stream<Arguments> createNegativeBinaryArguments() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(negativeArguments[0], "11111111111111111111111111110110"),
                Arguments.of(negativeArguments[1], "11111111111111111111111111001110"),
                Arguments.of(negativeArguments[2], "11111111111111111111011000111100"));
    }

    private Stream<Arguments> createPositiveOctalArguments() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(positiveArguments[0], "12"),
                Arguments.of(positiveArguments[1], "62"),
                Arguments.of(positiveArguments[2], "4704"));
    }

    private Stream<Arguments> createNegativeOctalArguments() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(negativeArguments[0], "37777777766"),
                Arguments.of(negativeArguments[1], "37777777716"),
                Arguments.of(negativeArguments[2], "37777773074"));
    }

    private Stream<Arguments> createPositiveHexArguments() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(positiveArguments[0], "A"),
                Arguments.of(positiveArguments[1], "32"),
                Arguments.of(positiveArguments[2], "9C4"));
    }

    private Stream<Arguments> createNegativeHexArguments() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of(negativeArguments[0], "FFFFFFF6"),
                Arguments.of(negativeArguments[1], "FFFFFFCE"),
                Arguments.of(negativeArguments[2], "FFFFF63C"));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = { "0" })
    void shouldReturnZeroIfValueNotSpecified(String zero) {
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toBinary());
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toOctal());
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toHex());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createPositiveBinaryArguments")
    void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbersBin(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
        decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
        assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createNegativeBinaryArguments")
    void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbersBin(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
        decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
        assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toBinary());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createPositiveOctalArguments")
    void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbersOrc(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
        decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
        assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toOctal());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createNegativeOctalArguments")
    void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbersOct(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
        decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
        assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toOctal());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createPositiveHexArguments")
    void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbersHex(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
        decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
        assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toHex());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("createNegativeHexArguments")
    void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbersHex(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
        decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
        assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toHex());
    }
}
```

I know i could just negate positiveArguments instead of creating another array but i want to stay it clear also maybe in future I will differentiate them.

Second approach: Organize each conversion type into nested classes. Reading about tests is more clear but the disadvantage is scrolling file / class in case of check / change testing arguments because I can't use outer class method sources (**or i dont know how(?)**):

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class DecimalRepresentationTest {

    private DecimalRepresentation decimal;

    private final int[] positiveArguments = { 10, 50, 2500 };
    private final int[] negativeArguments = { -10, -50, -2500 };

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        decimal = new DecimalRepresentation();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = { "0" })
    void shouldReturnZeroIfValueNotSpecified(String zero) {
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toBinary());
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toOctal());
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toHex());
    }

    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Decimal to Binary")
    class ToBinaryConversion {

        private Stream<Arguments> createPositiveBinaryArguments() {
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(positiveArguments[0], "1010"),
                    Arguments.of(positiveArguments[1], "110010"),
                    Arguments.of(positiveArguments[2], "100111000100"));
        }

        private Stream<Arguments> createNegativeBinaryArguments() {
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(negativeArguments[0], "11111111111111111111111111110110"),
                    Arguments.of(negativeArguments[1], "11111111111111111111111111001110"),
                    Arguments.of(negativeArguments[2], "11111111111111111111011000111100"));
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("createPositiveBinaryArguments")
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbers(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toBinary());
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("createNegativeBinaryArguments")
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toBinary());
        }
    }

    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Decimal to Octal")
    class ToOctalConversion {

        private Stream<Arguments> createPositiveOctalArguments() {
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(positiveArguments[0], "12"),
                    Arguments.of(positiveArguments[1], "62"),
                    Arguments.of(positiveArguments[2], "4704"));
        }

        private Stream<Arguments> createNegativeOctalArguments() {
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(negativeArguments[0], "37777777766"),
                    Arguments.of(negativeArguments[1], "37777777716"),
                    Arguments.of(negativeArguments[2], "37777773074"));
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("createPositiveOctalArguments")
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbers(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toOctal());
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("createNegativeOctalArguments")
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toOctal());
        }
    }

    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Decimal to Hexal")
    class ToHexalConversion {

        private Stream<Arguments> createPositiveHexArguments() {
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(positiveArguments[0], "A"),
                    Arguments.of(positiveArguments[1], "32"),
                    Arguments.of(positiveArguments[2], "9C4"));
        }

        private Stream<Arguments> createNegativeHexArguments() {
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of(negativeArguments[0], "FFFFFFF6"),
                    Arguments.of(negativeArguments[1], "FFFFFFCE"),
                    Arguments.of(negativeArguments[2], "FFFFF63C"));
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("createPositiveHexArguments")
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbers(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toHex());
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("createNegativeHexArguments")
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toHex());
        }
    }
}
```

Third approach: If I'm going for 2nd approach, creating new arguments method for each test case is little pointless, so I decided to put em as @CsvSource (because of only-constant annotation arguments i had to initialize arguments outside array):

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class DecimalRepresentationTest {

    private DecimalRepresentation decimal;

    static private final String POSITIVE_A = "10", POSITIVE_B = "50", POSITIVE_C = "2500"; 
    static private final String NEGATIVE_A = "-10", NEGATIVE_B = "-50", NEGATIVE_C = "-2500";   

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        decimal = new DecimalRepresentation();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = "0")
    void shouldReturnZeroIfValueNotSpecified(String zero) {
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toBinary());
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toOctal());
        assertEquals(zero, decimal.toHex());
    }

    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Decimal to Binary")
    class ToBinaryConversion {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"'" + POSITIVE_A + "', 1010",
                    "'" + POSITIVE_B + "', 110010",
                    "'" + POSITIVE_C + "', 100111000100"})
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbers(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toBinary());
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"'" + NEGATIVE_A + "', 11111111111111111111111111110110",
                    "'" + NEGATIVE_B + "', 11111111111111111111111111001110",
                    "'" + NEGATIVE_C + "', 11111111111111111111011000111100"})
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toBinary());
        }
    }

    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Decimal to Octal")
    class ToOctalConversion {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"'" + POSITIVE_A + "', 12",
                    "'" + POSITIVE_B + "', 62",
                    "'" + POSITIVE_C + "', 4704"})
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbers(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toOctal());
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"'" + NEGATIVE_A + "', 37777777766",
                    "'" + NEGATIVE_B + "', 37777777716",
                    "'" + NEGATIVE_C + "', 37777773074"})
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toOctal());
        }
    }

    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Decimal to Hexal")
    class ToHexalConversion {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"'" + POSITIVE_A + "', A",
                    "'" + POSITIVE_B + "', 32",
                    "'" + POSITIVE_C + "', 9C4"})
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForPositiveNumbers(int positiveNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(positiveNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toHex());
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @CsvSource({"'" + NEGATIVE_A + "', FFFFFFF6",
                    "'" + NEGATIVE_B + "', FFFFFFCE",
                    "'" + NEGATIVE_C + "', FFFFF63C"})
        void shouldReturnExpectedValuesForNegativeNumbers(int negativeNumber, String bitRepresentation) {
            decimal.setNumber(negativeNumber);
            assertEquals(bitRepresentation, decimal.toHex());
        }
    }
}
```

How do you see that? Which one should i use in this case? By the way when I testing something like my custom numeral system converter could i fully trust of Standard Java API and then instead of hardcoding expected results just use Java' 
Integer.toString(int i, int radix) method?

Comment: Readability would be one thing to consider. How far do I have to scroll to interpret your code. Something like the [fluent pattern](https://automatetheplanet.com/fluent-page-object-pattern/) is one approach to solve this where you have method chaining to add to each test.

Answer (score 0):

General guidelines I'd advise are:

- have each test test *one* thing. If you have more than one assert within a test, then if the first one fails, you never know if the later ones also fail or not -- by having multiple asserts, you are hiding the opportunity to potentially detect additional bugs.
- have each test stand on its own, so you don't have to rely on the order of tests. This is helpful when you also just want to re-run failed tests.
- yes, you should rely on the standard Java classes doing what they say. Writing unit tests for them would be more work than you need to do (basically, if they don't do what they say, we're all impacted - so they better; they've also been more thoroughly tested than any tests you are likely to write).
- Keep the tests simple and clear to read (apply the "KISS" principle, keep-it-simple-sally)

I realize this doesn't directly address your code layout, but perhaps it will help guide you to some decisions.

Comment: "Assert one thing" doesn't necessarily mean the same thing as "have only one assert statement". You can use `assertAll` to stack multiple asserts, but from a conceptual point of view, you want to assert only one concept per test, because otherwise it's harder to reason about what's broken.